# Loop through all Fields of a Type

Tags: c#, reflection

My general intention is to close all open `RegistryKey`s before closing the application. That is, without having to add a key.Close() for each particular key. I´d also wanted to avoid populating a `list<>` with the opened keys, as I thought may be another solution.

I was looking for a kind of iteration that would get me all RegistryKeys in my form and then close them with a foreach loop of some kind.

After much searching (and i mean, this whole day, which I feel is already too much for something that i get the feeling its very simple if you know how to) and reading much about handles, fields, properties and members, I´ve come to theese conclussions...

1- `Registrykey key1 = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Path")` is a field member. (I wasnt even sure sure WHAT it was.)

2- It is private since I didn´t specify otherwise.

After that, I guessed I might do something like

```
foreach (FieldInfo current in this.GetType().GetFields(
                                                       BindingFlags.Instance | 
                                                       BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                                       BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly))
{
    if (current.FieldType == typeof(RegistryKey))
    {
                RegistryKey key = (RegistryKey)current.GetValue(this);
                key.Close();
    }
}
```

But I am QUITE sure I am not closing the already opened key... just opening and closing a new one... Then again. I might (more than likely) be wrong.

My question made clear: Is what I´m trying to do viable or should I fall back to the `list<>` or one-line-per-key methods? Are my assumptions wrong?

**What would be the proper way of closing all registry keys on an application?**

Comment: `But I am QUITE sure I am not closing the already opened key... just opening and closing a new one... Then again. I might (more than likely) be wrong.` No; that actually does work.

Comment: This approach is very wrong.  You should close each key as soon as you're finished with it, using the `using` block.

Comment: Don't leave the keys open. open/read/close. Open/Write/Close. Think of it like a disconnected dataset.

Comment: @SLaks My reason to leave them open was because I have to access the same key to reach different values and with different purposes throughout the execution of the program. Opening and closing the key each time I needed to access it would make the code really hard to read as it would have a lot of near-identical lines. However, the `using` instruction and/or a helper method might ease this. I will think it through. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Acelnorst: refactor those identical lines into a function - problem solved!